# How to automate my Post production refresh steps like updating the configuration through Apex code using Tooling/Metadata API

Tags: apex, metadata-api, tooling-api

After every production refresh of Sandboxes I have to perform manual steps updating Custom Label, Remote Site Settings, Named Credential, Custom Settings and Custom Metadata. How can I automate the process using Apex code and the Metadata/Tooling API?

Answer (score 0):

*Custom Settings* you can retrieve via SOQL (or use standard [Custom Setting methods](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_custom_settings.htm#apex_methods_system_custom_settings)) and make any changes directly in Apex using DML.

You should consider using **Metadata API** for retrieving and updating the following: *Custom Label, Remote Site Settings, Named Credential and Custom Metadata*.

There is [Apex Wrapper Salesforce Metadata API](https://github.com/financialforcedev/apex-mdapi), which simplifies work with Metadata API.

**In my opinion**, using Metadata API approach will be advisable only if there are really a huge number of adjustments which you should perform after every Production refresh.